# How to use avro-python3 on Windows 10 to parse files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I have downloaded an AVRO file (with JSON payload) from Microsoft Azure to my Windows 10 computer:

[image: Azure Event Hub]

Then with python 3.8.5 and avro 1.10.0 installed via pip I have tried running the following script:

```
import os, avro
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open("48.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for d in reader:
    print(d)
reader.close()
```

Unfortunately, nothing is printed by the script.

Then I have searched around and have tried to add a schema as in below:

```
schema_str = """
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "EventData",
  "namespace" : "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "SequenceNumber",
    "type" : "long"
  }, {
    "name" : "Offset",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "EnqueuedTimeUtc",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "SystemProperties",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes" ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "Properties",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : [ "long", "double", "string", "bytes", "null" ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "Body",
    "type" : [ "null", "bytes" ]
  } ]
}
"""
schema = avro.schema.parse(schema_str)
reader = DataFileReader(open("48.avro", "rb"), DatumReader(schema, schema))
for d in reader:
    print(d)
reader.close()
```

But this hasn't helped, still nothing is printed.

While I was expecting that a list of dictionary objects would be printed...

**UPDATE:**

I've got a reply at the [mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r215d08ca7e8458a4cd3a626dd88bb90ab11f4d1aed0a4beedd38b9d6%40%3Cuser.avro.apache.org%3E) that avro-python3 is deprecated.

Still my issue with original avro persists, nothing is printed.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have to apologize - the avro file I was using did not contain any useful data. The reason for my confusion is that a colleague was using a different file with the same name while testing for me.

Now I have tried both avro and fastavro modules on a different avro file and both worked. I will look at PySpark as well.

Comment: fwiw, `fastavro` should work better

Comment: You could also probably use PySpark to read directly from Azure / WASB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OneCricketeer suggested use PySpark to read avro files generated by EventHub. Here, [PySpark: Deserializing an Avro serialized message contained in an eventhub capture avro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197825/pyspark-deserializing-an-avro-serialized-message-contained-in-an-eventhub-captu) is one such example.